# The CLASS function must be called from a class constructor

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find the type of a struct field.

I tried to call `prod` on what I thought was an array, but I got this error:

```
??? Error using ==> prod
Dimension argument must be a positive integer scalar within indexing range.
```

So I printed the object in question and found this:

```
K>> F.val

ans =

   0.110000000000000   0.890000000000000


ans =

   0.590000000000000   0.410000000000000   0.220000000000000   0.780000000000000


ans =

   0.390000000000000   0.610000000000000   0.060000000000000   0.940000000000000
```

Which is different than the output of an array, which is this:

```
K>> [0.11 0.89 0.59 0.41 0.22 0.78 0.39 0.61 0.06 0.94]

ans =

  Columns 1 through 4

   0.110000000000000   0.890000000000000   0.590000000000000   0.410000000000000

  Columns 5 through 8

   0.220000000000000   0.780000000000000   0.390000000000000   0.610000000000000

  Columns 9 through 10

   0.060000000000000   0.940000000000000
```

and when I call `class` on the object, I get this error:

```
K>> class(F.val)
??? Error using ==> class
The CLASS function must be called from a class constructor.
```

How can I find the type of `F.val`?

Comment: what is the output of `>> which class` in your command line?

Comment: I guess `F.val` is a cell array. You can `>> iscell(F.val)` to check this out. To convert it to an array you can simply `>> [F.val{:}]`

Comment: If you like, you can also drill down into the structure in the GUI - double-click in the workspace variables window or `openvar('F')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`F` is most likely an array of structures. Thus, calling `class(F.val)` is like calling `class(F(1).val, F(2).val, F(3).val)`, which is different than the one-input-element syntax.

Use `class(F(1).val)` to obtain the class of `val` of the first element of `F`.

By the way, the error with `prod` is very likely of similar origin. `prod(F(1).val)` works fine, however, with two inputs, the second is assumed to be a dimension argument, and that needs to be an integer (which can be of `class double`, though).